# How to keep java.lang.reflect when use proGuard

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

In my application I want use this **library** : https://github.com/xmuSistone/AndroidPileLayout

And I want use `proguard` in my project, when `proguard` my project show me may bugs.

For fix `proguard`, the library developer say:

> proguard works wrong when you are using java.lang.reflect api, please
>   check your own code.

How can I fix it and keep `java.lang.reflect`?

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection will need to have absolute path the the classes and its respective methods. So, you need to tell proguard to leave the stuff you need alone. You can describe this in your `proguard-rules.pro` file. 
Example:

```
-keep public class fully_qualified_classname
-keepclassmembers public class fully_qualified_classname  {
    # will ignore all methods
    public <methods>;
    public static final String static_instance_variable_if_any;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you send to me code with `java.lang.reflect` ? i am amateur and really need your help. please

Comment: @Hock are you using reflection in your code anywhere?